# Javascript remove event listener made in object

Tags: javascript, events

I using the code below to add an event listener to the body but I can't remove it

```
this.events = {
    addEventListener : function(element, eventName, eventHandler, scope) {
        var scopedEventHandler = scope ? function(e) { eventHandler.apply(scope, [e]); } : eventHandler;
        if(document.addEventListener)
            element.addEventListener(eventName, scopedEventHandler, false);
        else if(document.attachEvent)
            element.attachEvent("on"+eventName, scopedEventHandler);
    }
}
this.events.addEventListener( document.body, "keydown", this.keyEvent, this);
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've written when you tried to remove the event?

Comment: if (document.addEventListener)  { // Standard
document.body.removeEventListener('keydown', this.keyEvent, false); 
} else  { // IE
document.body.detachEvent('onkeydown', this.keyEvent); 
}

Comment: I've also tried making a remover listener function in the same style but it makes no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By modifying the event handler in your `this.events` object, the event handlers are no longer the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/asXzA/1/

I suggest you create a registry of events added via your `this.events` system, that way you can pull stuff out easily.

```
this.events = {
    eventRegistry : {},

    addEventListener : function(element, eventName, eventHandler, scope) {
        var scopedEventHandler = scope ? function(e) { eventHandler.apply(scope, [e]); } : eventHandler;

        // save the scoped event handler
        if (typeof eventRegistry == "undefined")                
            eventRegistry = {};

        if (typeof eventRegistry[eventName] == "undefined")
            eventRegistry[eventName] = {};

        eventRegistry[eventName][eventHandler] = scopedEventHandler;

        if(document.addEventListener)
            element.addEventListener(eventName, scopedEventHandler, false);
        else if(document.attachEvent)
            element.attachEvent("on"+eventName, scopedEventHandler);
    },

    removeEventListener : function(element, eventName, eventHandler, scope) {

        // retrieve saved event handler
        var scopedEventHandler = eventRegistry[eventName][eventHandler];

        if(document.removeEventListener)
            element.removeEventListener(eventName, scopedEventHandler, false);
        else if(document.detachEvent)
            element.detachEvent("on"+eventName, scopedEventHandler);
    }
};

this.keyEvent = function () { alert("keypressed"); this.events.removeEventListener(document.body, "keydown", this.keyEvent, this); alert("removed"); };
this.events.addEventListener( document.body, "keydown", this.keyEvent, this);​
```

Comment: Great that has worked but alas has not fixed the problem I was having, for some reason when the key is pressed it is producing a new object as well as referencing the current one, it's ok in Safari but not Firefox.

Comment: the firefox problem is a link that sets all this off is staying in focus even though I change focus in the object.

Comment: My solution does not help you remove the event handler?

I don't quite understand what you mean by "staying in focus" and "producing a new object". Are you still talking about the same piece of code you posted? Thx.

Comment: Sorry it appeared that the key press was triggering two objects instead of one but this seems to be a bug in firefox, so if a link has focus and you hit return it will trigger that link as well as the key command, the link will create the object so I have just shifted the focus and then I can use return without making another object. I guess it's not a bug but IE and Safari don't do that.

Comment: That'll be a separate question. Do post another, with the code, after you accept this for "removing event handler".